# How to get the last full day timestamp using javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to get the beginning time timestamp for the last full day. I can do it in ruby but I need help doing it in javascript.

```
(Time.now.to_s.split(" ")[0] + " 00:00:00").to_time.to_i - 86400
```

I tried to do it like this but it's not giving me the right value.

```
new Date(new Date().toString().split(" ")[0] + "00:00:00").getTime()/1000 - 86400;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby:

```
Time.now.to_s.split(" ")[0]
#  => "2015-03-20"
```

In JavaScript:

```
new Date().toString().split(" ")[0];
# => "Fri"
```

As a result you're code will result `NaN` as output.

Try this instead:

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
# => "2015-03-20"
```

This will make your existing JS as:

```
new Date(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10) + " 00:00:00").getTime()/1000 - 86400;
```

**Note:** The results might vary between Ruby and JavaScript, as Ruby `.to_time` will convert string into `UTC` by default, whereas JS `new Date` will convert string into `GMT`. You can specify TimeZone in either (or both) of them to output same answer.